# How to git apply a diff file that contains special characters (åäö)

Tags: git

**Update 3**: *Turns out that my problem was with the line endings after all*, the reason that I believed there was something wrong with the encoding was probably because my text editors failed to display the correct encoding (or, more likely my failure to understand them). *My issue could be resolved using --keep-cr when applying the patches.*

My input files have mixed encoding ANSI/UTF-8, Swedish chars (åäö) and probably line ending issues aswell. Using the following set of create/apply patches, I can now successfully apply patches:

```
git format-patch [myhash]
git am [patchdir]/*.patch --keep-cr
```

---

I am trying to apply a patch that contains diffs with swedish characters (åäö) but when doing so, git-apply reports *error while searching for*: .... swedish characters here ...

If I look at the particular file in a text editor, I am *able to find the exact text that git-apply is looking for*. I am aware of problems with line endings/whitespace, but this does not seem to be such issue.

1st attempt I created/applied the patches using MINGW64 (git version 2.10.0.windows.1) and this created patch-files that made my åäö looked funny so I suspected there was some encoding issue.

2nd attempt I used a "normal windows command prompt" together with git.exe and <strike>this seemed to create nice patch files (I could read the åäö in a plain text editor)</strike> so I thought these patches could be applied but no, same issue.

It doesn't matter if I use git.exe in command prompt or via MINGW64, the patches created by format-patch looks the same, just my text editor (Notepad++) that probably cant understand the encoding.

Update2: I found out that the patch that I am trying to apply contains diffs from two different files, both containing Swedish characters, but with different file encodings. The first file is ANSI (cp1252) and the second one is UTF-8. When examining the patchfile, I can see that either the diffs from the ansifile or the utf-8 file gets screwed up (or at least looks screwed up in Notepad++). If I switch the encoding in Notepad++ between ANSI and UTF-8, I can see one set of Swedish characters. This led me to believe that I had found the problem, but I cant seem to recreate the error when creating a very simple repository containing only two files. I am unsure which encoding is really used for the patch file since it somehow seems to support the Swedish characters in the patch file even when the originate from two files with different encodings.

Comment: Are you using the 'git format-patch' command? It should create a UTF8 encoded patches

Comment: yes, I am using git format-patch. Running this command through MINGW64 or windows command prompt seems to create patches with different encoding though.

Comment: What's the encoding of the file?

Comment: @choroba The encoding of the input file is cp1252 (ANSI), the patch-file also seems to have the same encoding

Comment: @EmilG: What about converting the patch to UTF-8?

Comment: @choroba Good idea, I will try that.

Comment: @choroba: Exact same result (error while searching for...). Have tried with utf-8 with/without BOM.